# ingress-nginx, cert-manager and ingressClassName

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager, ingress-nginx

I recently upgraded `ingress-nginx` to version 1.0.3.

As a result, I removed the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation from my ingress, and put `.spec.ingressClassName` instead.

I am running `cert-manager-v1.4.0`.

This morning I had an email saying that my Let's Encrypt certificate will expire in 10 days. I tried to figure out what was wrong with it - not positive that it was entirely due to the ingress-nginx upgrade.

I deleted the `CertificateRequest` to see if it would fix itself. I got a new `Ingress` with the challenge, but:

1. The challenge ingress had the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation set correctly, even though my ingress has `.spec.ingressClassName` instead - don't know how or why, but it seems like it should be OK.
2. However, the challenge ingress wasn't picked up by the ingress controller, it said:

`ingress class annotation is not equal to the expected by Ingress Controller`

I guess it wants only the `.spec.ingressClassName` even though I thought the annotation was supposed to work as well.

So I manually set `.spec.ingressClassName` on the challenge ingress.  It was immediately seen by the ingress controller, and the rest of the process ran smoothly, and I got a new cert - yay.

It seems to me like this will happen again, so I need to know how to either:

1. Convince `cert-manager` to create the challenge ingress with `.spec.ingressClassName` instead of `kubernetes.io/ingress.class`.  Maybe this is fixed in 1.5 or 1.6?
2. Convince `ingress-nginx` to respect the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation for the challenge ingress.  I don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Which version did you upgrade ingress from? So I installed on GKE cluster `ingress-nginx` `1.0.4` + `cert-manager` `v.1.4.0`, I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour, once it's stuck due to different error and I saw my `challenge ingress` didn't have `class` specified, however after fixing another error, certificate was issued successfully. If you can replicate this error again, please share this chain `certificate` -> `certificate request` -> `order` -> `challenge` to see where and why it gets stuck.

Comment: @moonkotte: I upgraded from `0.48.1`. Since this is a non-production system, I don't mind trying to reproduce this failure before `cert-manager` decides it's time to renew the cert.  How do I manually trigger the renewal process to see if this happens?  Delete the `Certificate`?  The `Secret`?

Comment: I tested different versions of `nginx` as well, starting `1.0.0` `ingressClass` is shipped within (I installed/upgrade/downgrade everything via `helm`). To restart the whole process it's enough to delete `secret`, this way certificate will remain the same, new `certificateRequest` and other chain will be created

Comment: I'm going to try this now

Comment: deleting the secret seems to have caused the `CertificateRequest` and `Order` to be created, but I see no `Challenge` nor any `Ingress` created, and the certificate is not renewed.  How do I test this? @moonkotte

Comment: @e.dan Try to describe `order`. It should have events with some clues on what happens.

Comment: Also, found in documentation the correct way of certificate renewal - [check this out](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/certificate/#actions-triggering-private-key-rotation)

Comment: @moonkotte - that's good to know.  tried it, and it succeeded. It must have been some older Order/Challenge from before the upgrade that failed. I'm hoping for the best, and this seems to work.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue

The issue was fixed by certificate renewal, it works fine without manually set `spec.ingressClassName` in challenge ingress (I saw it with older version), issue was somewhere else.

Also with last available (at the writing moment) `cert-manager v1.5.4` challenge ingress has the right setup "out of the box":

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
---
$ kubectl get ing
NAME                        CLASS    HOSTS            ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-szxfg   nginx    dummy-host       ip_address      80        11s
```

### How it works (concept)

I'll describe main steps how this process works so troubleshooting will be straight-forward in almost all cases. I'll take a `letsencypt staging` as an `issuer`.

There's a chain when `certificate` is requested to be created which `issuer` follows to complete (all resources have owners - previous resource in chain):

`main ingress resource` -> `certificate` -> `certificaterequest` -> `order` -> `challenge` -> `challenge ingress`.

Knowing this, if something failed, you can go down by the chain and using `kubectl describe` command find where the issue appeared.

### Troubleshooting example

I intentionally added a wrong domain in ingress to `.spec.tls.hosts` and applied it. Below how the chain will look like (all names will be unique!):

See certificates:

```
$ kubectl get cert
NAME                     READY   SECRET                          AGE
lets-secret-test-2       False   lets-secret-test-2              15m
```

Describe `certificate` we are interested in (you can notice I changed domain, there was already secret):

```
$ kubectl describe cert lets-secret-test-2
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From          Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    16m   cert-manager  Existing issued Secret is not up to date for spec: [spec.commonName spec.dnsNames]
  Normal  Reused     16m   cert-manager  Reusing private key stored in existing Secret resource "lets-secret-test-2"
  Normal  Requested  16m   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "lets-secret-test-2-pvb25"
```

Nothing suspicious here, moving forward.

```
$ kubectl get certificaterequest
NAME                           APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER                REQUESTOR                                         AGE
lets-secret-test-2-pvb25       True                False   letsencrypt-staging   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   19m
```

Describing `certificaterequest`:

```
$ kubectl describe certificaterequest lets-secret-test-2-pvb25
Events:
  Type    Reason           Age   From          Message
  ----    ------           ----  ----          -------
  Normal  cert-manager.io  19m   cert-manager  Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Normal  OrderCreated     19m   cert-manager  Created Order resource default/lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393
```

Again, everything looks fine, no errors, moving forward to `order`:

```
$ kubectl get order
NAME                                  STATE     AGE
lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393   pending   21m
```

It says `pending`, that's closer:

```
$ kubectl describe order lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393

Events:
  Type    Reason   Age   From          Message
  ----    ------   ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Created  21m   cert-manager  Created Challenge resource "lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393-3788447910" for domain "dummy-domain"
```

`Challenge` may shed some light, moving forward:

```
$ kubectl get challenge
NAME                                             STATE     DOMAIN           AGE
lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393-3788447910   pending   dummy-domain   23m
```

Describing it:

```
$ kubectl describe challenge lets-secret-test-2-pvb25-2336849393-3788447910
```

Checking `status`:

```
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://dummy-domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxyyyyzzzzz': Get "http://dummy-domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxyyyyzzzzz": dial tcp: lookup dummy-domain on xx.yy.zz.ww:53: no such host
  State:       pending
```

Now it's clear that something is wrong with `domain`, worth checking it:

Found and fixed the "mistake":

```
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress configured
```

Certificate is `ready`!

```
$ kubectl get cert
NAME                     READY   SECRET                          AGE
lets-secret-test-2       True    lets-secret-test-2              26m
```

### Correct way to renew a certificate using cert-manager

It's possible to renew a certificate by deleting corresponding secret, however [documentation says it's not recommended](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/certificate/#actions-triggering-private-key-rotation):

> Deleting the Secret resource associated with a Certificate resource is
> **not a recommended solution** for manually rotating the private key. The
> recommended way to manually rotate the private key is to trigger the
> reissuance of the Certificate resource with the following command
> (requires the kubectl cert-manager plugin):
>
> `kubectl cert-manager renew cert-1`

`Kubectl cert-manager` command installation process is described [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/kubectl-plugin/#installation) as well as other commands and examples.

### Useful links:

- [Certificate in cert-manager - concept](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/certificate/)
- [Cert-manager - certificate request](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/certificaterequest/)
- [ACME Orders and Challenges](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/acme-orders-challenges/)

Comment: I am still suffering from this - oftentimes when cert-manager creates the ingress for the solver, it's without `ingressClassName`. I am now running cert-manager v1.8.0 and ingress-nginx v1.1.3. When I manually add the `ingressClassName` then it works.  It seems related to https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4821 and/or https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4537
Any clue how I can fix this once and for all?